# google.setOnLoadCallback with jQuery $(document).ready(), is it OK to mix?

Tags: javascript, jquery, onload, google-ajax-api

I'm using Google Ajax API and they suggest I use `google.setOnLoadCallback()` to do various things related to their API but I'm using also jQuery's `$(document).ready()` to do other JS things, not related to Google API.

Is it safe to mix these two approaches in one document? I did not notice any problems yet but I suppose it's a matter of scale.

Comment: Do you mean that you are using the [Google API loader](https://developers.google.com/loader/) which can be found in the file [jsapi](https://www.google.com/jsapi)?

Answer (score 69, accepted):

You pretty much have to do this:

```
google.setOnLoadCallback(function() {
  $(function() {
    // init my stuff
  });
});
```

You can't do `$(document).ready()` without `$` (the jQuery object) being available, so that needs to go inside the callback.  And you can't be sure the document is ready inside the callback, so you have to do `ready()` too.

Comment: You mean we should mention ready function inside the google callback function?

Comment: @dilip I think (starting at the $) that's just an alternate syntax for  $(document).ready(/* init my stuff */), so yes.

Comment: This seems more complicated than necessary.  Just use $(function(){//do stuff here}); instead of the google.setOnLoadCallback().

Answer (score 49):

Sorry to be raising this from the dead, but 1) It still comes up as an 'answer' to this problem and 2) I've found a better solution.

There is an optional 3rd argument on the `google.load` function that takes an object of configuration options. One of the options is `callback`.  It also gets rid of the need for a separate `setOnLoadCallback` call.

E.g.

```
google.load('visualization', '1.0', {
    'packages': "charttype", 
    'callback': $jQ.proxy(me.setupChart, me)
});
```

So:

```
<script src="https://www.google.com/jsapi"></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function () {
    function mapsLoaded() {
        etc etc etc
    }

    google.load("maps", "2", {"callback" : mapsLoaded});
});
</script>
```

See:
https://developers.google.com/loader/#Dynamic

Answer (score 6):

If your JavaScript code resides in its own js file and not inside the HTML document you could also do this in the document:

```
<script>
        google.load("jquery", "1.7.0");
        google.load("jqueryui", "1.8.16");
        google.setOnLoadCallback(function() {
             var script = document.createElement("script");
             script.setAttribute("type", "text/javascript");
             script.setAttribute("src", "my.js");
             document.getElementsByTagName("html")[0].appendChild(script);
        });
</script>
```

This loads `my.js` after all other stuff is loaded from google. In your `my.js` file you can then do `$(document).ready(...)`. So your application code is independent from "loaded by google" or "loaded directly from your server".

Answer (score 4):

Why mix when you can do it all with `$(document).ready()`?  Just get rid of the `google.setOnLoadCallback` function and use jQuery's `$(document).ready()`.

**This:**

```
google.setOnLoadCallback(chartEnrollment);
```

**becomes**

```
$(document).ready(chartEnrollment);
```

Comment: Or in naked JS: `document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", chartEnrolment);`

Comment: So there is a guarantee that the criteria for when `chartEnrolment` would be called when set as a callback via `google.setOnLoadCallback` will always be met when it is set via `$(document).ready()`? Can you give a reference for this?